# How do I get back the Unity login screen after installing gnome-core?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

I installed `gnome-core` and now I have an ugly login screen. I want to reset or delete `gnome-core` and re-install the Unity login screen, or just switch back to LightDM. Is there any way to do it easily and quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` to switch between LightDM and GDM. So you'll reconfigure GDM even if it's LightDM you want to use.

Comment: i tried that and it didnt work i want my login screen looks like that http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/LightDM_1.2.1_on_Ubuntu_12.04.png

Comment: its working. I figuret it out ... but it dont work when i click lock screen...